# Re-clone repository from Github gui tool

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I have an unresolved conflict between my two machines on an IOS project, and I want to reload the project on my laptop. How do I do that?

I tried deleting the repository directory, then going to the location of the repository on the site and pressing the "Clone in desktop" link. But all it does is open my GitHub GUI tool, and there's nowhere to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Took me 20 minutes to figure it out. So simple that I didn't even think about it.

Just click on sync on the github app. It pushes and pulls.

[GitHub Guide](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/index.html#pullit)

Answer (score 0):

A couple options:

1. The repo you deleted might just be sitting in your trash. So if you empty the trash then when you click on the repo in GitHub for Mac it will say that it can't find the repo and would you like to Reclone or Remove.
   OR
2. In Github for Mac go to the Repository list, right click on the repo and select Remove, this only takes it out of the list. To remove it completely, delete the folder in Finder. Now you can clone it again with File->Clone Repository